# What's the semantic version of the same software for different OS?

Tags: versioning, semantic-versioning

What's the semantic version of the same software for different OS ?

For exemple : X.Y.Z
X is a major version
Y is a minor version
Z is a patch

If I have the same version but for 3 different OS; How can I call them ?

I don't find the answer in semver.org or in google..

Comment: Semantic versioning doesn't have anything to say about the OS a particular piece of software runs on.  Change the *name of the software* to indicate that it is OS-specific.

Comment: I don't know if you'd even change the name of the software. I've never seen the OS-name get appended onto the software name... I think it's a matter of just knowing which executable you've downloaded and that it will run on a particular OS... Like if you're on Windows you don't download the package that runs on Linux.

Comment: @StevieV: Maybe not for the actual executable, but certainly for installers.  `SomeSoftwareSetup_Win64.exe`

Comment: @RobertHarvey The installers are executable, so I guess you were right. So... I guess not for the software "title"?

Comment: No, not for the actual executable, just for the installer.  If it's an executable from a managed language like Java or C#, you can set some metadata in the executable's manifest indicating what operating system it is built for.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Have you ever considered writing a software engineering book?

Comment: @StevieV: Why?  I'm not nearly qualified enough, just very opinionated.  I've had first-hand experience working with overblown architectures created by others, and seeing the problems they cause, so I'm deeply skeptical when anyone trots out the phrases "the right way" or "the best practice."

Comment: @RobertHarvey I think that you bring a lot of information (on a variety of design concepts) to the table that helps people make the right decision. If all of that information were collected in one place, that would be a good thing.